# Shortest Path in a Unit Cost DAG BFS in Hadoop

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, hadoop

Just got done implementing a shortest path algo of a unit cost DAG BFS in Hadoop and wanting to get anyone's opinion on how I could have done it better. The main issue I see is that I lose the parallel nature of hadoop by forcing the mappers to wait for the output of the previous mapper before beginning.

The thing works and finds the shortest path given two input files: nodes.txt and edges.txt.

nodes.txt represents all the nodes in the DAG and is of the form

```
1 "A"
2 "B"
3 "C"
4 "D"
5 "E"
6 "F"
7 "G"
8 "Z"
9 "X"
```

edges.txt represents all the edges of the DAG and is of the form

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 5
2 6
3 5
3 6
4 7
5 8
6 8
7 8
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class ShortestPathDAGBFS
{

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        HashMap<String, String> nodes = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> edges = new HashMap<>();
        String sourceNodeId;
        String destNodeId;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\S\\n]{1,4}");
        boolean found = false;

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException
        {
            nodes = GlobalFunctions.parseNodesFile(context.getConfiguration().get("Nodes"));
            edges = GlobalFunctions.parseEdgesFile(context.getConfiguration().get("Edges"));
            sourceNodeId = GlobalFunctions.findNodeId(context.getConfiguration().get("Source"), nodes).trim();
            destNodeId = GlobalFunctions.findNodeId(context.getConfiguration().get("Dest"), nodes).trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String[] edge = pattern.split(line.toString());
            edge[0] = edge[0].trim();
            edge[1] = edge[1].trim();
            LinkedList<String> outNodes = edges.get(edge[1]);
            String newPath = edge[0] + "->" + nodes.get(edge[1]);
            if (outNodes != null && !found)
            {
                for (String nextNodeId : outNodes)
                {
                    context.write(new Text(newPath.toString()), new Text(nextNodeId.toString()));
                    if (nextNodeId.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(destNodeId))
                    {
                        context.getCounter("FoundDest", "FoundDest").increment(1);
                        found= true;
                        context.write(new Text(edge[0].toString()), new Text(edge[1].toString()));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        String destNodeId;
        HashMap<String, String> nodes = new HashMap<>();
        boolean written = false;

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException
        {
            nodes = GlobalFunctions.parseNodesFile(context.getConfiguration().get("Nodes"));
            destNodeId = GlobalFunctions.findNodeId(context.getConfiguration().get("Dest"), nodes);
        }

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text prevPath, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            for (Text newestNode : values)
            {
                if (newestNode.toString().trim().equals(destNodeId) && !written)
                {
                    String destNode = context.getConfiguration().get("Dest");
                    String path = prevPath.toString().replace("->", " ");
                    path += " " + destNode;
                    context.write(new Text(path), null);
                    written = true;
                }
                else if (!written)
                {
                    context.write(new Text(prevPath.toString()), new Text(newestNode.toString()));
                    System.out.println("Reducer output: " + prevPath.toString() + " " + newestNode.toString());
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static class GlobalFunctions
    {

        public static HashMap<String, String> parseNodesFile(String nodesPath) throws IOException
        {
            HashMap<String, String> nodes = new HashMap<>();
            Path path = new Path(nodesPath);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), new Configuration());
            InputStream is = (fs.open(new Path(path.toUri().toString())));
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset())))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] node = line.replace(' ', '\0').split("\"");
                    nodes.put(node[0].trim(), node[1].trim());
                }
            }
            return nodes;
        }

        public static HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> parseEdgesFile(String edgesPath) throws IOException
        {
            HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> edges = new HashMap<>();
            Path path = new Path(edgesPath);
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), new Configuration());
            InputStream is = (fs.open(new Path(path.toUri().toString())));
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset())))
            {
                String line;
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\S\\n]{1,4}");
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] edge = pattern.split(line);
                    LinkedList<String> adjacencyList = edges.get(edge[0]);
                    if (adjacencyList == null && !edge[0].equals(edge[1]))
                    {
                        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
                        list.add(edge[1]);
                        edges.put(edge[0], list);
                    }
                    else if (!edge[0].equals(edge[1]))
                    {
                        adjacencyList.add(edge[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return edges;
        }

        public static String findNodeId(String source, HashMap<String, String> nodes)
        {
            for (Entry<String, String> e : nodes.entrySet())
            {
                if (e.getValue().equals(source))
                {
                    return e.getKey();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class FirstMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
    {

        HashMap<String, String> nodes = new HashMap<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\S\\n]{1,4}");
        String sourceNodeId;

        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException
        {
            nodes = GlobalFunctions.parseNodesFile(context.getConfiguration().get("Nodes"));
            sourceNodeId = GlobalFunctions.findNodeId(context.getConfiguration().get("Source"), nodes).trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String[] edge = pattern.split(line.toString());
            edge[0] = edge[0].trim();
            if (sourceNodeId.equals(edge[0]))
            {
                context.write(new Text(nodes.get(edge[0])), new Text(edge[1]));
                System.out.println("Writing for first iteration" + edge[0] + " " + edge[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(args);
        String[] arguments = parser.getRemainingArgs();
        if (arguments.length != 5)
        {
            usage(System.out);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Configuration conf = parser.getConfiguration();
        conf.set("Source", arguments[3]);
        conf.set("Dest", arguments[4]);
        conf.set("Nodes", arguments[0]);
        conf.set("Edges", arguments[1]);

        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(ProblemIII.class);
        job.setMapperClass(FirstMap.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, arguments[1]);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("tmpout-part0"));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        boolean found;
        long outputBytes;
        int iteration = 0;
        do
        {
            job = initJob(conf);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("tmpout-part" + iteration));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("tmpout-part" + (iteration + 1)));
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
            found = job.getCounters().findCounter("FoundDest", "FoundDest").getValue() == 1 ? true : false;
            outputBytes = job.getCounters().findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter", "MAP_OUTPUT_BYTES").getValue();
            ++iteration;
        } while (!found && outputBytes != 0);
        if (outputBytes == 0)
        {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            FSDataOutputStream file = FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).create(new Path(arguments[2]+"/output.txt"));
            file.writeChars(arguments[3] + " null " + arguments[4]);
            file.close();
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        else
        {
            Job finalJob = initJob(conf);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(finalJob, "tmpout-part" + (iteration));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(finalJob, new Path(arguments[2]));
            System.exit(finalJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }

    private static void usage(PrintStream out)
    {
        out.println("usage: ProblemIII <nodes path> <edges path> <output path> <source protein> <destination protein>");
    }

    private static Job initJob(Configuration conf) throws IOException
    {
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(ProblemIII.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        return job;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Hadoop, take my advice with care.

1. Are you sure that you want to use the default charset?

   > ```
   > try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.defaultCharset()))) {
   > ```

   It could vary from system to system. Usually it's a good idea using UTF-8 explicitly.
2. Since both `newPath` and `nextNodeId` are `String`s,

   > ```
   > context.write(new Text(newPath.toString()), new Text(nextNodeId.toString()));
   > ```

   could be

   ```
   context.write(new Text(newPath), new Text(nextNodeId));
   ```

   It's the same, since `String.toString` has the following implementation:

   ```
   public String toString() {
       return this;
   }
   ```

   (There are other similar occurrences in the code, find them.)
3. As far as I see `Text` has a constructor which accepts `Text` parameters. You might want to use that instead of converting it back to `String`:

   > ```
   > context.write(new Text(prevPath.toString()), new Text(newestNode.toString()));
   > ```
4. The `setup` method also queries `Dest`. You might want to store that in a field or move it outside the loop:

   > ```
   > for (Text newestNode: values) {
   >     if (newestNode.toString().trim().equals(destNodeId) && !written) {
   >         String destNode = context.getConfiguration().get("Dest");
   > ```
5. You could invert the conditon in the `map` method to [make the code flatten](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/):

   ```
   @Override
   public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) 
           throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       String[] edge = pattern.split(line.toString());
       edge[0] = edge[0].trim();
       edge[1] = edge[1].trim();
       List<String> outNodes = edges.get(edge[1]);
       String newPath = edge[0] + "->" + nodes.get(edge[1]);
       if (outNodes == null || found) {
           return;
       }
       for (String nextNodeId: outNodes) {
           context.write(new Text(newPath), new Text(nextNodeId));
           if (nextNodeId.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(destNodeId)) {
               context.getCounter("FoundDest", 
                   "FoundDest").increment(1);
               found = true;
               context.write(new Text(edge[0].toString()), 
                   new Text(edge[1].toString()));
               return;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Actually, I guess the found check could be right at the beginning:

   ```
   @Override
   public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context) 
           throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       if (found) {
           return;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
7. The `reduce` method also could use a [guard clause](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). If I'm right it could even break the loop since if `written` is `true` both nested conditions will be `false`.

   ```
   @Override
   public void reduce(Text prevPath, 
           Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
           throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       for (Text newestNode: values) {
           if (written) {
               break;
           }
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
8. > ```
   > sourceNodeId = GlobalFunctions.findNodeId(context.getConfiguration().get("Source"), nodes).trim();
   > ```

   `findNodeId` could be a little bit smarter. All of the four uses of it trim its output and pass an object which is get
   from `context.getConfiguration().get("somekey")`. A wrapper like this could eliminate some duplication:

   ```
   public static String findTrimmedNodeId(
           Configuration configuration, 
           String key, Map<String, String> nodes) {
       return findNodeId(configuration.get(key), nodes).trim();
   }
   ```
9. The `fs` variable is unused here:

   > ```
   > FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
   > ```

   Are you sure that these statements are required?
10. I'd change `ShortestPathDAGBFS` to `ShortestPathDagBfs`

    From *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*:

    > While uppercase may be more common, 
    >   a strong argument can made in favor of capitalizing only the first 
    >   letter: even if multiple acronyms occur back-to-back, you can still 
    >   tell where one word starts and the next word ends. 
    >   Which class name would you rather see, HTTPURL or HttpUrl?
11. Calling the mapper `Map` is confusing. I'd choose `DagBfsMapper` or something descriptive. The same is true for `Reduce`.
12. `HashMap<...>` reference types should be simply `Map<...>`, as well as `LinkedList<...>` could be `List<...>` (*Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*)
13. Consider using [`LineIterator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html), it would simplify the code a little bit.
14. Try to use more descriptive variable names:

    > ```
    > Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\S\\n]{1,4}");
    > ```

    What is this pattern supposed to match?